# Java - Intercepting methods using guice?

Tags: java, annotations, inversion-of-control, guice

I am trying to implement method interception using guice.
I want to be able to annotate methods and intercept them and I am getting an error when trying to call bindInterceptor.

The error is:
**The method bindInterceptor(Matcher, Matcher, MyInterceptor) is undefined for the type MyModule**

Am i doing anything wrong?

```
public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation arg0) throws Throwable {
        return arg0.proceed();
    }
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @interface MyAnnotation {}

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
            // I get an error on this line
        bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class), 
                new MyInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not having an issue getting this to compile and run with the interceptor working using guice 3.0.  What do your import statements look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is usually the result of getting the wrong `import` for one of `Matchers`, `AbstractModule`, or `MethodInterceptor`.

What are the import lines for these three? You should have:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.matcher.Matchers;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
```